# Filtering items when a feild is pressed in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen with different cards (that has article information) am trying to filter the articles by categories when ever the convenient category is pressed i want that category to be selected and the articles that belong to that category to show and , on the other hand all articles from all the categories to show when no category is selected ( this will make more sense if you look at the picture bellow )

The code used to showing the pictures of the diffrent categories  :

```
import TouchableScale from "react-native-touchable-scale";
import { category } from "../api/data";

import colors from "../config/colors";

function HotTopics({ navigation }) {
  //const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  return (
    <View style={styles.Container}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.CategoryText}>Hot Topics</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}
        data={category}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <TouchableScale
                  activeScale={0.9}
                  tension={50}
                  friction={7}
                  useNativeDriver
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate({ id: item.id })}
                >
                  {/* to show the horizental news list*/}

                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: item.image }}
                    style={{
                      width: 100,
                      height: 120,
                      borderRadius: 16,
                      marginRight: 10,
                    }}
                  />

                  {/* to show the news titles inside the pictures*/}
                  <SharedElement
                    id={`item.${item.id}.text`}
                    style={{
                      width: 100,
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 95,
                      //left: 10,
                      paddingHorizontal: 5,
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.blogTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                  </SharedElement>
                  {/* to show the pictre of the author of the news article*/}

                  {/* to show the name of the author and read time of article*/}
                </TouchableScale>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The code used for showing the articles cards bellow : (ArticleList.js)

```
function ArticleList({ navigation, post }) {
  if (!post.length) {
    return null;
  } // so we dont show anything untill we have articles
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <Text style={styles.HeadText}>Popular</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subText}>Show all</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={post}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableScale
              activeScale={0.9}
              tension={50}
              friction={7}
              useNativeDriver
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", { data: item })
              }
            >
              <Card item={item} />
            </TouchableScale>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

And on the main screen i call ArticleList.js and filter the data like this :

```
// for filtering the data 
const filterResultsByCategory = (category) => {
    return post.filter((onepost) => {
      return onepost.category === category;
    });
  };
// to show the data 
<ArticleListVer post={filterResultsByCategory("Politics")} />
```

the code used for the main screen :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import ArticleList from "../components/ArticleList";
import ArticleListVer from "../components/ArticleListVer";
import Categories from "../components/Categories";
import HotTopics from "../components/HotTopics";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import useArticles from "../hooks/useArticles";
import usePosts from "../hooks/usePosts";
function MainScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [Category, setCategory] = useState();
  const [loadApi, data, errorMessage] = useArticles();
  const [loadPost, post] = usePosts();
  const filterResultsByCategory = (category) => {
    return post.filter((onepost) => {
      return onepost.category === category;
    });
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {/* header Date and title */}
      <LinearGradient
        colors={["#353540", "#353540", "#1E1E24"]}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      >
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <Header headerTitle="TODAY'S ARTICLES" />
            {/* haeder Categories */}
            <Categories />
            {/* show the data in a flatlist */}
            <ArticleList data={data} navigation={navigation} />
            {/* show the categories in a flatlist*/}
            <HotTopics onCategorySelect={this.setCategory} />
            {/* show the vertical Article list */}
            <ArticleListVer
              post={filterResultsByCategory(this.state.category)}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
}
MainScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerShown: false,
  };
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
export default MainScreen;
```

Comment: Why do you have a navigation in the hottopics onpress ?

Comment: I was just trying stuff out I was thinking it will be a lot easier to send the user to another screen with the filtered data, but having the change on the main screen is more user friendly

Comment: Yes, you can have a simple call back function as a prop and do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to have a callback function to set the state from the HotTopics component something like below

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState();
```

In render

```
  <HotTopics onCategorySelect={setCategory} />
  <ArticleListVer post={filterResultsByCategory(category)} />
```

for the onclick of the hottopic you can do

```
onPress={() =>
            this.props.onCategorySelect(item.category)
          }
```

By doing this you will re render the parent with new Category. and for reset you will need a button to reset the state to empty so that you will show all items.

Comment: in the render part will be used on a diffrent screen ( the main screen ) so this will probably give me an undefined error right ?

Comment: the state, the filter function you gave and the render should be placed in the main screen

Comment: If you want, you can update the question with the parent screen, I can give you the full code then :)

Comment: thank you for your help , i just updated my main question with the parent screen

Comment: <ArticleListVer
              post={filterResultsByCategory(this.state.category)}
            /> should change to <ArticleListVer
              post={filterResultsByCategory(Category)}
            /> as you are using a hooks based implementation

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: it works thank you so much , i only have one question why the this.state thing doesnt work on hooks based implementation ?

Comment: state is only available in class components only for function components you have use hooks like the above implementation :)